# How to manage spaces in paths to format files?

Tags: paths, format-files

I have noticed that

```
pdflatex \&"/path with a space/mylatexformat" file.tex
```

does not work whereas

```
pdflatex \&"/path/without/space/mylatexformat" file.tex
```

works well.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: as I said in a comment on your other question just use \&mylatexformat and add the directory to the TEXFORMATS setting in texmf.cnf

Comment: I wanted to avoid playing with TEXFORMATS...

Comment: why?  it's no different from using `\documentclass{amsart}` instead of `\input /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls` All of TeX assumes path search.

Comment: why what? The format I create has to be in folder whose path contains a space... :( It is in the "Application Support" folder of `OSX`...

Comment: @Colas it is easy to avoid spaces, if you can not avoid them always you can always make a link in the filesystem `ln -s "/path with a space/mylatexformat.fmt . ; pdflatex \&mylatexformat` would work as latex would see the symbolic link

Comment: @Colas I meant why don't you want to use TEXFORMATS path (which is there for this reason)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it possible to modify TEXFORMATS from a shell? And how to do it? I don't know much about UNIX...

Comment: `TEXFORMATS="/path with a space/" pdflatex \&mylatexformat` (all on one line) probably works

Comment: Creating a symbolic link made it. Thanks for your help and sorry to disturb with so many questions...

Comment: OS X is idiotic in this regard. I always overcame its idiocy by creating symbolic links. Now I just use a saner OS., but symbolic links are certainly a less radical answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have given an answer (with the symbolic links). I am using this one (easier for than to change `TEXFORMATS`). Sorry if this is unpolite. I wanted to avoid you to write the answer. If you do write an answer (with the symbolic link trick included), I will delete mine. A BIG thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to this issue has been to create a symbolic link from `/path with a space/mylatexformat.fmt` to the directory where `latex` is executed.

Comment: It is considered polite (here) to allow the person who made the "right" comment to be given a chance to provide the answer. Who knows, perhaps the commentator will expand on his/her answer and provide an even better answer than was possible in the comments....